# What is the total size of VS2017 Community Edition for offline ?

Tags: filesize, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition, visual-studio-community

What is the total size of VS2017 Community Edition for offline? Downloaded 25.4 GB  which took 1 day and 4 hours and the command script are still running. Confuse, when my VS2017 download will finish.

Answer (score 1):

I finally downloaded and found the total size of VS2017 Community Edition for offline which is of 30 GB[screen shot of image property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdbg0.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded full Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.9.4 on 28-Dec-2018. Total size is around 43.6 GB. It took around 5-6 hours on 5 MB/S internet speed.